# Show how to compute $2^{343}$ using the least multiplication.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Show how to compute $2^{343}$ using the least multiplication.

Comment: What's wrong with $$343=7^3\implies 2^{343}=\left(\left(2^7\right)^7\right)^7\;--\text{ three operations}\;?$$

Comment: @DonAntonio least number of multiplication of integers is asked.

Comment: @mjqxxxx That is the binary expansion of $343$. If the exponent must be a power of two, how would you write $8$?

Comment: Note that the best is actually somewhat better than the 13 given here; in fact, you can do it in just 11 steps.  These are canonically known as _addition chains_ and you can find more information about them under that name.

Comment: It might be worth altering the question to ask for the _decimal_ expansion of $2^{343}$. As a number, it already is what it is. And in binary, it's as simple as a $1$ followed by $243$ zeros.

Answer (score 5):

We can get to $x^{343}$ in $11$ multiplication steps.

Here is a path:
$$x^2,\quad x^3,\quad x^6,\quad x^{12},\quad x^{24},\quad x^{48},\quad x^{49},\quad x^{98},\quad x^{196},\quad x^{294},\quad x^{343}.$$

The procedure is similar to the one of mjqxxx. but gets to $x^{49}$ in $7$ steps instead of $8$.

Comment: Is 11 the minimum?

Comment: Yes, $11$ is the minimum.

Comment: Any proof? Or is there a program that computes the minimum?

Comment: Ah, https://oeis.org/A003313/b003313.txt .

Comment: There are programs. I knew $11$ was the minimum (OEIS). Spurred by that, I found a trick that would give it. There may be other addition chains of length $11$.

Comment: Out of curiosity, in general what kind of computational complexity is required to determine the addition chain in the first place? Does that outweigh the advantage over repeated squaring?

Comment: As far as I know there is no known efficient way to determine the addition chain for an arbitrary exponent

Answer (score 4):

If you have $x$, you can calculate $x^7$ in four integer multiplications:

- $x \cdot x = x^2$
- $x^2 \cdot x^2 = x^4$
- $x^4 \cdot x^2 = x^6$
- $x^6 \cdot x = x^7$.

Since $343=7^3$, this means you can calculate $2^{343}$ in twelve multiplications: four to go from $2$ to $2^7$, four to go from $2^7$ to $(2^7)^7=2^{49}$, and four to go from $2^{49}$ to $(2^{49})^7=2^{343}$.

Answer (score 4):

One way to do this (and probably the way the prof wants) is [exponentiation by squaring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring). Note that $x^{2n} = (x^n)^2$ and $x^{2n + 1} = (x^n)^2 \cdot x$. We can either break down $343$ into smaller pieces this way, but it's easier to think about starting at the bottom:

$$
\begin{array}{ccc}
Value & Computation & Multiplications & Total Multiplications \\
2^2 & (2^1)^2 & 1 & 1 \\
2^5 & (2^2)^2 \cdot 2 & 2 & 3 \\
2^{10} & (2^5)^2 & 1 & 4 \\
2^{21} & (2^{10})^2 \cdot 2 & 2 & 6 \\
2^{42} & (2^{21})^2 & 1 & 7 \\
2^{85} & (2^{42})^2 \cdot 2 & 2 & 9 \\
2^{171} & (2^{85})^2 \cdot 2 & 2 & 11 \\
2^{343} & (2^{171})^2 \cdot 2 & 2 & 13 \\
\end{array}
$$

How did I pick these numbers? Look at the binary expansion of $343 = 101010111_2$. Starting at the second-left digit, for each $1$, square and multiply, and for each zero, just square. Note that each computation only uses $2$ and the previous computation, so you don't have to store any auxilary results. If you really wanted to, you could write $2^{343}$ as (this is what starting from the top looks like):
$$ \left( 2^{171} \right)^2 \cdot 2 $$
$$ \left( \left( 2^{85} \right)^2 \cdot 2 \right)^2 \cdot 2 $$
$$ \left( \left( \left(2^{42} \right)^2 \cdot 2 \right)^2 \cdot 2 \right)^2 \cdot 2 $$
$$\vdots$$
$$ \left( \left( \left( \left( \left( \left( \left( 2^2 \right)^2 \cdot 2 \right)^2 \right)^2 \cdot 2 \right)^2 \right)^2 \cdot 2 \right)^2 \cdot 2 \right)^2 \cdot 2 $$

Because we don't store any auxilary results, this method is one multiplication slower than mjqxxxx's method, but this one generalizes much more cleanly. Which you should use depends on if you want a general method or just speed (in which case, perhaps a lookup table is appropriate?)